# Prove that when $\lambda$ is large enough

Tags: asymptotics, complex-integration

\begin{align}
f(z)=  \frac{1}{2\pi j }\int_{\mathcal{C}}\frac{1}{ \lambda}\frac{\mathrm{\Gamma}(c+s)}{\mathrm{\Gamma}(c+1)}\frac{\mathrm{\Gamma}(b+1)\lambda^{s}}{\mathrm{\Gamma}(b+s)}z^{-s}ds=\frac{1}{2\pi j}\int_{\mathcal{C}}\frac{\mathrm{\Gamma}\left(\Phi-1+s\right)}{\mathrm{\Gamma}\left(\Phi\right)} \Psi^{-s+1}z^{-s}ds, \forall z \in \mathbb{R}^{*}_{+}, s\in \mathbb{C}
\end{align}

Comment: You say that "This process was used in one of the scientific articles and the author of the article did not give an idea about the proof or a reference from which this property was derived."  Perhaps you could give us a reference this paper your were reading...

Comment: Yes ofcorse, you will find in the proof of theorem 1 what I meant.  https://eudl.eu/doi/10.1007/978-3-319-24540-9_28

Comment: Not the words 4 lines from the bottom " uniformly in $s$". That means it works, as in my answer.

Comment: I understood now, thank you very much for your help and your precious comments @Peter

Answer (score 1):

The condition $g(z, s, \lambda) \sim h(z,s)$ as $\lambda\to\infty$ for each $z, s$, is equivalent to $$\frac{g(z, s, \lambda)}{h(z,s)}\to 1 \text{ as } \lambda \to \infty \text{ for each } z, s$$
and this is not strong enough to ensure the required result. However if instead we had
$$\frac{g(z, s, \lambda)}{h(z,s)}\to 1 \text{ uniformly in $s$ as } \lambda \to \infty \text{ for each } z$$
it would work.

As a counterexample for the first, consider $D(s, \lambda)$ defined by

$D(s, \lambda)=|\lambda|$ for $-\frac{1}{\lambda}<s<\frac{1}{\lambda}$ and $D(s,\lambda)=0$ otherwise. Note that

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}D\left(s,\lambda \right)ds=1 \text{  for each $\lambda$, and that}$$ $$D(s,\lambda)\to0 \text{ as }\lambda \to\infty \text{  for each $s\ne 0$ .}$$

If we define $g(z,s,\lambda)=h(z,s)+D(s,\lambda)$, then we see that

$$g(z, s, \lambda) \sim h(z,s)\text{ as }\lambda\to\infty \text{ for each $z$ and $s$,}$$ since when $\lambda$ is large enough ($\lambda>|\frac{1}{s}|$), we have $D(s,\lambda)=0$. Also

$$f(z) = \int_{0}^{\infty}g\left(z,s,\lambda \right)ds = \int_{0}^{\infty}h((z,s)+D(s,\lambda) ds$$ $$= \int_{0}^{\infty}h((z,s) ds+1\ne\int_{0}^{\infty}h((z,s) ds$$

The result works with uniform convergence. We have
$$ 1-\delta < \frac{g(z, s, \lambda)}{h(z,s)}<1+\delta \text{ whenever $\lambda>L(z,\delta)$, so (taking $h$ to be positive)}$$
$$ (1-\delta).h(z,s) < g(z, s, \lambda)<(1+\delta).h(z,s) \text{ whenever $\lambda>L$.}$$
It follows that $$ \frac{1}{1+\delta}g(z, s, \lambda)<h(z,s)< \frac{1}{1-\delta}g(z, s, \lambda) \text{ whenever $\lambda>L$. Integrating gives}$$
$$ \frac{1}{1+\delta}.f(z)<\int^{\infty}_{0}h(z,s)ds < \frac{1}{1-\delta}.f(z) \text{ and as this holds for every $\delta>0$ }$$
$$ f(z)=\int^{\infty}_{0}h(z,s)ds \text{   as required }$$

Comment: Do you mean by uniformly in s that: lim {g(z,s,lambda)-h(z,s)}/h(z,s)=0 as lambda tends to +infty. Hence f(z) as required

Comment: @PeterSmith I would like to show you my case exactly if it is correct by considering your precious answer

Comment: @Toufik The basic difference between normal convergence and convergence uniform in $s$ is that when you choose a small $\delta$ and find $L$, the same $L$ works for every value of $s$. If you have normal convergence you might need to choose a different $L$ for every $s$, and this could mean there are values of $s$ in the range of integration for which the inequalities in the 3rd-last line are not valid. If you are able to edit the question to add extra information - on the end please - I can have a look.

Comment: I appreciate your answer @Peter. I edit the question by adding more information about this issue.